# Clicking "Pictures" of a point cloud in PCL Library or Open3D

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, open3d

I have a point cloud and want to take "pictures" of it from various angles. Let us say I point my at the top at a certain angle and rotate the camera around the object at this particular orientation and "snap" what the camera is seeing.

Next I want to change the camera orientation and repeat the process.

I am completely new to the 3D data processing domain and not very well aware of all the PCL / open3D libraries. How can I code this functionalities.

Thanks in Advance.